# Focusable issue in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Currently I am working on a crappy GUI. What I am trying to do is listen for when the user presses "enter". When they press enter, I will take the text they have written in the `JTextField` & clear the `JTextField`.

However, no keypresses are being registered. No matter what, any buttons I press are registered as text & put into the JTextField - so if I press enter, its never heard by the `JFrame` I applied the listener to.

Observe:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, typing results in the `JTextField` there. Even when I click out of the `JTextField`, it still has focus & the main frame does not 'hear' the keypresses.

How should I approach this?

Comment: [How to write an action listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and before any one suggests it, no, do not, use a `KeyListener`

Comment: If you need something more like a "global" key listener, then you should be using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will overcome the limitations of `KeyListener`

Comment: Why not add an `ActionListener` to the text field? When the field is in focus & the user presses enter, it will detect the action. As to activating with the enter key no matter what has focus, use key bindings as suggested by @MadProgrammer, but as an end user, I'd find that to be counter intuitive. There is a lot to providing the user with the 'path of least surprise' & it seems like you're trying to achieve the opposite.

Comment: You might also consider doing some research into "default button" which can be associated with the `JRootPane` of the `JFrame`

Comment: Thanks for the help @MadProgrammer. I suppose I should just add an actionlistener to it the textfield? I thought those only detected buttonclicks though? Edit - I could just get whatever is calling it, & determine that if it is the JTextField, then to clear the text right after I suppose.

Comment: Add a `ActionListener` to a `JTextField` will only tell you want the user presses the [Enter] key while the field has focus.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you might even be able to use a `DocumentListener` to detect when the text is changed

Comment: Is there any chance you could show me a quick example? I made an anonymous class attached to the JTextField, but obviously its not going to register button clicks... I dont know. EDIT - Nevermind, I'm a fool. I had no idea the actionPerformed would pick up on an Enter keystroke